Error adding custom fields to Outlook calendar event using schema extension
I'm trying to add custom fields to an Outlook calendar event using the Graph API. According to the docs this should be possible using schema extensions.
I managed to create the schema extension using this code (note: I needed to log in using a work account, otherwise I got the following error: Unable to find target address)
const schemaExtension = {
  id: 'testCustomFields',
  description: 'Testing custom fields',
  targetTypes: ['event'],
  properties: [
    {
      name: 'customField1',
      type: 'String',
    },
    {
      name: 'customField2',
      type: 'String',
    },
    {
      name: 'customField3',
      type: 'String',
    },
  ],
};

client.api('/schemaExtensions').post(schemaExtension);

However, when trying to create or update an event containing the extended fields, I run into errors.
First try:
const eventToUpdate = {
  start: {
    dateTime: '2024-11-15T10:00:00Z',
    timezone: 'UTC',
  },
  end: {
    dateTime: '2024-11-15T18:00:00Z',
    timezone: 'UTC',
  },
  subject: 'Updated Subject',
  extlwrky7um_testCustomFields: {
    customField1: 'test1',
    customField2: 'test2',
    customField3: 'test3',
  },
};
client
  .api('/me/calendars/' + calendarId + '/events/' + event.id)
  .update(eventToUpdate);

This results in the following error response: Requests must contain extension changes exclusively.
For this error I found a similar question here, which stated that this is a known issue, and updating the extended fields only should work.
If I try to only update the extended fields, the error is different:
const eventToUpdate = {
  extlwrky7um_testCustomFields: {
    customField1: 'test1',
    customField2: 'test2',
    customField3: 'test3',
  },
};
client
  .api('/me/calendars/' + calendarId + '/events/' + event.id)
  .update(eventToUpdate);

In this case the error is: Request is not supported.
Any recommendation on how to solve this?

Are you able to debug/inspect if .update() method sends PATCH or PUT request?
